# Will a 12 AWG circuit handle a TIG welder rated at 28 amps when set for 220V?

Tags: wiring

I bought a 110/220V TIG welder rated at 28 amps at 220V. Duty cycle varies with output. It has a 12 AWG power cord. Garage now has a 220V circuit with 12 AWG.

Comment: What's the maximum duty cycle, and is that 28A an I1max, I1eff, or rated primary current figure?

Comment: Chart in manual shows "Rated Input Current 28A" This is when set for TIG welding at 220V. It's a multiple function AHP Alpha-TIG 200X. A non-AHP site shows a 60% duty cycle at max output

Answer (score 2):

### Close, but not quite

Given the 60% max duty cycle figure you stated for your welder, and a rated primary current of 28A, your circuit ampacity comes out to 28 * 0.78 = 21.84A.  In other words, to run your welder at that 60% duty cycle, you need 10AWG wire with a 25 or 30A breaker; or, you can reduce the duty cycle to avoid overloading the circuit, as going down to 50% duty cycle gets you to just under 20A given the 28A rated primary current of your welder.

(P.S. if you're wondering where in the Code this lives, it's 630.11(A) and the associated Table.)

Comment: From Art. 630.11(A) "Alternatively, if the Ieff [effective current] is not given, the ampacity of the supply conductors shall not be less than the current value determined by multiplying the rated primary current in amperes given on the welder rating plate by the factor shown in Table 630.11(A) based on the duty cycle of the welder." TPE correctly shows that calculation and the resulting ampacity requirement.

Answer (score 0):

12AWG from the breaker to the receptacle would be a code violation for more than a 20 amp breaker, regardless of the size of the wire in the cord-and-plug on the device.

Comment: Welders are weird man -- see Art. 630 for details

Comment: TPE correctly points out that welders are special equipment and hence have a separate article in the Code.

Comment: Does not matter how weird they are - if the breaker is more than 20A, the wire from the breaker to the receptacle must be more than 12Ga. If you are going to run the welder on a 20A breaker and hope it does not trip, fine - but if you are going to run a larger breaker, you need bigger wire in the wall, regardless of what's plugged into it at the far end.

Comment: I agree, the problem is the receptacle, which means nothing prevents you from plugging a non-welder in there. Unless it is keyed so only a welder can plug on, and one fit for 12 AWG...

Comment: @Harper -- you'd put a 5-20P on the welder in that case, anyhow